# Freeze formula that references cell in another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm working in a Google Sheets document that has two sheets, `Sheet1` and `Sheet2`. `Sheet2` has a cell, `A3`, with the formula `=Sheet1!A3`. This pattern holds throughout the column – e.g. `A4` in `Sheet2` has formula `=Sheet1!A4`, etc. Without getting into too much detail of the why, essentially the `A` column in `Sheet1` is to be reflected in the `A` column of `Sheet2`. My desire is that when `Sheet1` is updated, those changes will be reflected in `Sheet2`.

The problem is that when I add/delete entries into/from column `A` in `Sheet1`, Google Sheets automatically updates the formulas in `Sheet2` in a way I don't want it to. For example, say I insert a cell above `A3` in `Sheet1`, so that there is now new information in `A3` and the previous `A3` is now shifted down to `A4`. When I check out `Sheet2` I want the new `A3` from `Sheet1` to be reflected in `Sheet2`'s `A3`. However, the formula in `Sheet2`'s `A3` cell has now been updated to `=Sheet1!A4` (so that `Sheet2`'s `A3` still shows the information from `Sheet1`'s original `A3`), and all subsequent cells have been shifted by one as well. I can see a reason for this auto-updating functionality, but it is a hinderance in this case.

In looking up a solution, I've found out about absolute reference, i.e. changing the formula in `A3` to `=Sheet1!$A$3`, but this unfortunately does not help in my case.

Is there any way to prevent this autoupdating of the cell reference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Sheet2 use INDIRECT. Example

Add the following formula to Sheet2!A1

```
=INDIRECT("Sheet1!A:A")
```

The above will not be "affected" by row/column changes made into Sheet1 because it doesn't make a direct reference to rows/columns on Sheet1.

Answer (score 2):

Non-volatile equivalent of INDIRECT could be INDEX.

```
=index(Sheet1!a:a, 3)
```

Unfortunately, filling down for `index(Sheet1!a:a, 4)`, etc is difficult if not impossible. You could represent the **3** with a row reference to a worksheet that will never have rows deleted; e.g. `row(sheet2!b3)`. That shouldn't change unless you add/delete rows on sheet2 while allowing add/delete rows on sheet1.

Comment: An alternative is `={Sheet1!A:A}`

Comment: That;s true but only if you want row 3 from sheet1 put into row 3 in sheet2. My solution above is easily adaptable to non-row-to-row scenarios where a row offset is involved.

Comment: (@Rubén - besides, I didn't feel like typing out a long winded explanation of row *inference* which the OP is almost certainly going to ask for.) btw, I don't think you require the braces or CSE for `=sheet1!A:A`

Comment: On Google Sheets whitout braces we will get only the first value.